# Converting back to plain text when using ActionText

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, actiontext

First let me say that I love what Rails 6 has to offer in ActionText. Unfortunately when I declare it for an attribute in something like a post model:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_rich_text :body
end
```

I can't access the body's text anymore. It becomes an ActionText instance. I completely understand this is how this functionality works but there are times I need to pass the plain text of the body to other external methods. In my case I'm using the body in my meta-description tags with a gem called meta-tags. Doing so results in this error:

```
Expected a string or an object that implements #to_str
```

This is because what was before a plain text column becomes an AT instance:

```
=> #<ActionText::RichText id: 39, name: "body", body: #<ActionText::Content "<div class=\"trix-conte...">, record_type: "Post", record_id: 161, created_at: "2019-08-17 17:34:27", updated_at: "2019-08-17 17:34:27">
```

Seeing that it had getter methods attached with it I tried to do something like `@post.body.body` but this is actually

```
=> #<ActionText::Content "<div class=\"trix-conte...">
```

Also note that I've tried to create a method inside the post model but once has_rich_text is declared I no longer have original access to my body's text.

I'm not exactly sure how to:

- Extract my original content from the body attribute Convert it to
  plain text without html

Answer (score 27, accepted):

So apparently ActionText instances have a method for retrieving plain text values with `to_plain_text`. All together it looks like this:

```
@post.body => <div>This is my markup</div>
@post.body.to_plain_text => This is my markup
```

Comment: beautiful!!!...

Answer (score 1):

on top of [to_plain_text](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActionText/Fragment/to_plain_text), we can call [squish](https://apidock.com/rails/String/squish) to remove the new line '\n'

Answer (score 1):

Yes the answer by [Carl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57538897/473040) is correct

```
@post.body.to_plain_text #=> This is my markup without image
```

However if you have any attachments (eg blob image) inside your action text then they will  appear like

```
@post.body.to_plain_text #=> This is my markup with image[PXL_20210808_152511813.jpeg]
```

This is due to [this code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/815f282203ef001fa85cf320b4c4f59f25717c77/actiontext/lib/action_text/engine.rb#L43) which is called on every attachment when `#to_plain_text` it called

If you are in a case where you don't want to Display text for blob attachments you need to overwrite `ActiveStorage::Blob#attachable_plain_text_representation`

One way to do this:

```
# config/initializers/active_storage_overrides.rb

module ActiveStorageBlobOverrides
  def attachable_plain_text_representation(caption = nil)
    ""
  end
end

Rails.configuration.to_prepare do
  ActiveStorage::Blob.send :prepend, ::ActiveStorageBlobOverrides
end
```

How are you will end up with:

```
@post.body.to_plain_text #=> This is my markup with image
```

I hope this will save you a couple of hours of debugging