# how can I eliminate the html tags generated along with the content in the view page, written using the Action text(trix Editor)?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, wysiwyg, trix

I installed Action text (Trix Editor) in my Rails Application.

After writing the content,the content is generated along with the html tags.
e.g.

```
 "div class="trix-content"> div> This is the content part. br>br> /div>
```

Comment: What is the code that generated this ?

Comment: I just checked the trix editor README, and see [this comment about the "trix-content" class](https://github.com/basecamp/trix#styling-formatted-content). Does that answer your question?

Comment: Are you saying the output shows the content along HTML tags?  You will need to use something like `<%= sanitize(@object.content) %>` where `@object` is your variable and `.content` is whatever the field is actually called

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a built in function for this:

```
content.to_plain_text
```

Comment: the above function does remove the html tags, however it creates the multi paragraph to single paragraph. However, using **==** in a view page while rendering solves the problem.

Comment: If you have attachements the name of the files will still be added to the body text.

Comment: @StevenAguilar there is a solution to that issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57538658/converting-back-to-plain-text-when-using-actiontext

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the `<div class="trix-content">` surrounding your content, and cannot rely on overriding `views/layouts/action_text/contents/_content.html.erb`, you can quite bluntly Regexp your way through:

```rb
# Assuming your model uses `has_rich_text :content`
def contents
  content.to_s.gsub(/\A<div class="trix-content">(.*)<\/div>\z/m, '\1').strip.html_safe
end
```